# Why is my scp rejected from port 22 even though I'm connecting on port 25000?

Tags: openssh

I know others have had this issue, but I can’t extrapolate a solution to my situation.  I am trying to `scp` a `.tar.gz` file onto my newly configured Ubuntu server (I’m new to server config), but I’m being refused from port 22 even though I’ve set my port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to 25000.  Here is my log on `scp -v nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to nickeleres.com [127.0.1.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host nickeleres.com port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

**UPDATE** new error logs after enforcing `port 25000`

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host nickeleres.com, user root, command scp -v -t ~
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to nickeleres.com [184.168.221.35] port 25000.
debug1: connect to address 184.168.221.35 port 25000: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host nickeleres.com port 25000: Connection refused
lost connection
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo service ssh restart` after changing the port?

Comment: yes I did.  is there another port other than the one I changed in `/sshd_config` that needs to be updated from `22` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert the new `ssh` port number (25000) of the destination `scp` should connect to, otherwise it will try to connect to the default `ssh` port (22). Change your command to following:

```
scp -v -P 25000 nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~
```

Also note that you are writing to the root's home directory, make sure you have the right permissions. Another thing to note is the last `~` is not needed because if you don't mention the destination location `scp` will copy into home directory (`~`) of the remote user. So the following will do:

```
scp -v -P 25000 nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:
```

**EDIT:**

As 'ThomasW.' has pointed out, you can alternatively use the following:

```
scp -v -oPORT=25000 nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~
```

Comment: Alternatively, `scp -v -oPORT=25000 nickeleres.tar.gz root@nickeleres.com:~` - I ran into `-P` not working in the past, and replaced it with `-oPORT=PORTNUM` which seems to enforce the port number.

Comment: please see the updated error log in my original post after running each variation of the command

Comment: @redress: Previously `nickeleres.com` was resolving to 127.0.0.1, now 184.168.221.35. Please make sure you are connecting to the right host, use IP address if you are not sure.